# Display a value selected from a datePicker to a textField inside an alertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Good Day,

My workout app allows the user to build their custom workouts using a bar button '+' that opens an alert controller.  I have two text fields and a date picker as part of the alert controller.  Currently, a selection from the datePicker does not display the selection in the textField.  How can this be done?

[image]

Here's the code for the alert controller:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Workout", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        
        let newWorkout = Workout()
        newWorkout.name = self.nameTextField.text!
        newWorkout.dateCreated = self.datePicker.date
        newWorkout.time = self.timeTextField.text!

        print("Date \(self.datePicker.date)")
                    
        self.saveWorkout(workout: newWorkout)
    } )
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        return
    }
    
    alertController.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
    alertTextField.placeholder = "Workout Name"
        self.nameTextField = alertTextField
    }
    
    alertController.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        self.doDatePicker()
        alertTextField.inputView = self.datePicker
        
        alertTextField.placeholder = "DD MMM YYYY HH:MM:SS"
        self.dateTextField = alertTextField
    }
    
    alertController.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
    alertTextField.placeholder = "Average Time"
        self.timeTextField = alertTextField
    }
    
    alertController.addAction(addAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func doDatePicker(){

    datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 220, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
    datePicker.timeZone = .current
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

}
```

I appreciate any guidance provided.